# 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target'

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, gradle, java-8

IntelliJ complains with the following exception when I try to make my project.

```
Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target'
Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.8'
```

But a 'gradlew clean install' works just fine.

The project setup is:

gradle version 2.3

scala 2.10 and java

3 of the 4 modules use java 1.7 (source and target compatibility), the 4th module has source and target compatibility 1.8 and is causing the problem.

Any ideas how I can avoid the error? (moving to java 7 is not an option, upgrading scala is)

Comment: Is intelliJ running on java 7?

Comment: The about screen says 1.8_20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gradle by default use the ant task to build Scala code, and https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8966 shows that jvm 1.8 was not added as a supported target until Scala 2.11.5.

You can try using the Zinc  based compiler with by adding the following the gradle build file.

```
    tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
      scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false
    }
```

You may also need to add the zinc compiler to your dependency list.

Comment: hm, the gradle build actually works, it's only inside intellij that I see this problem. Well I'll upgrade the scala version and see what happens.

Comment: Accepted, because this points in the right direction. I still don't understand the details, but upgrading to scala 2.11 in the build script fixed the problem in intellij

Answer (score 17):

In Intellij IDEA (15 CE) add this scalac compiler option:

*Build, Execution, Deployment* -> *Compiler* -> *Scala Compiler* -> Default

*Additional compiler options*: `-target:jvm-1.7` (was empty).

There were also profiles Gradle 1, ... with `-target:jvm-1.8`, so I changed them also to `-target:jvm-1.7`.

I'm using Scala 2.10, JVM 1.8, source compatibility 1.7. It helped in my case.

Comment: After doing the above , i got the exception Error:scala: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.8' , @Bohumir Zamecnik

Comment: For posterity, "Build, Execution, Deployment" is found in File -> Settings

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error message using IntelliJ 2017.2.5 w/ JRE 1.8.0, scala 2.10.5 and gradle 3.3.  I solved my problem by checking the "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" checkbox in IntelliJ's IDE located at

Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle>Runner

Details can be found here: https://docs.gradle.org/4.2.1/userguide/scala_plugin.html#ideaTargetVersion and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html

Of note, I was able to build my gradle project outside of IntelliJ (i.e. cmd line) and only received this error on attempting to build using the IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: yeah why to change build.gradle when it can be solved with this it's the right answer

Comment: This worked for me for a similar issue with Java 11.

Answer (score 7):

I was searching for a solution for this for ages, finally found it - sharing for anyone else reading this.

Taken from: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5523902

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JDK 1.8 as your IntelliJ Project SDK, then the default project language level and source compatibility may be set to version 8 by default. This will also be reflected in IntelliJ's Scala compiler settings.

To override default Java 8 language level, it was only necessary for me to add the following to my `build.gradle`:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
```

After doing that, make IntelliJ IDEA import the Gradle project again. You should then confirm that the change has been picked up by IntelliJ by checking under:  *Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Scala Compiler*

Look at the *Additional compiler options* field for each of the modules listed and make sure that it contains `-target:jvm-1.7`, and not `-target:jvm-1.8`.

Under *Project Settings -> Modules*, you should see that the *Language Level* is now set to *7* too.

N.B. Setting the `sourceCompatibility` property under the Gradle properties `allprojects`, `subprojects` or using `tasks.withType(ScalaCompile)` did not work for me; it had to be specified separately to be picked up.

(This worked for me using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3, Gradle 4.1, the Gradle Scala plugin and Scala version 2.10)

Comment: Adding `sourceCompatibility = 1.7` and `targetCompatibility = 1.7` did the trick for me (Gradle 4.6, Scala 2.10.2 project, IntelliJ 2018). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have resolved by removing conflict between scala-sdk mentioned in POM and importing in global libraries.

Check scala-sdk version in the pom.xml and also check the global libraries scala-sdk you have added. it should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding from @Alan Effrig's answer.
JVM 1.8 was not added as a supported target until Scala 2.11.5.

In my IDE, Scala version was selected as 2.11.0, updating it to latest 2.11.12 solved the issue.