# Transform a java project into a scala project (Intellij)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle project written in Java and want to turn the whole thing into a scala project (still gradle). Which steps are necessary to do so?

Since java code should be fully supported in scala, this shouldn't be to hard. I tried it, but I cannot write scala code within my code now.

I started defining the main method in scala and it seems like Intellij has no idea what I try to do.

What I did so far:

- apply plugin: 'scala' --> in build.gradle
- compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.6' --> in build.gradle
- I started a new java gradle project and moved all the packages/files over.

There is no compile error if I let the code as it is right now.

Do I need to define another "project sdk"?

Comment: Perhaps try 'Project > Add Framework Support... > Scala'. But I think this is only for building with IntelliJ not Gradle.

Comment: I tried it, but there is no option for scala.

Comment: That's odd. Have you installed the Scala plugin? The dialog looks like this for me: https://i.imgur.com/PsYkEPX.png - after adding that, I could compile a formerly pure Java project with additional Scala sources.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have issues with compiling scala code witnin new project (rec-imported).

Do you have scala-library as dependency in your project?
If not, you can add Global library to Project structure.

Comment: Yeah, I have it as dependency.

Comment: Give some more information: what kind of compilation errors do you have? Have you added scala plugin to gradle? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

Comment: Now that I changed the filename from ".java" to ".class" it seems better. The exception I get now is `Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target'`.

Comment: Known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041527/jvm-1-8-is-not-a-valid-choice-for-target

Comment: I tried the accepted solution, but it doesn't work for me. I cannot "compile the module" though, as I meantioned wrongly on another comment. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, try if it compiles in Gradle from command line (`gradle compile`). Based on what you say, it should; if it doesn't, fix this first.

If it does, add Scala plugin in IDEA (if it isn't already installed) and you may need to activate Scala support explicitly as mentioned in @0__'s comment.

Comment: Forget my other comment, I cannot compile the module itself somehow.