# Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.9' is not a valid choice for '-target'

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea

Created a new clean Scala project using Gradle.

This is the only dependency:

```
compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.4"
```

When building on the command line `./gradlew build` works perfectly fine. However, when using IntelliJ it gives me this warning:

```
Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.9' is not a valid choice for '-target'
Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.9'
```

I have both the JDK with java 8 and 9 installed, but I'm currently using JDK 1.8. But I'm not sure if that's related.

Comment: There is a similar question here, maybe the answers will be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041527/jvm-1-8-is-not-a-valid-choice-for-target

Comment: The answers there didn't solve my problem

Comment: Did you check `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Scala Compiler`, specifically if target:jvm is set, and what jvm is used for `scala compiler server` if you use it?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Does delegate actions to gradle option help as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46794316/2000323 ?

Answer (score 7):

In Scala 2.12, the Scala compiler always compiles to Java 8 compatible bytecode.

You can find more info below:

1. [Compiling and testing Scala 2.12](http://lira.epac.to:8080/doc/gradle/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:scala_cross_compilation)
2. [Scala-lang: JAVA 8 BYTECODE FOR LAMBDAS](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#java-8-style-bytecode-for-lambdas)

Add the following lines to your build.gradle:

```
compileScala.targetCompatibility = 1.8
ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
```

Comment: Add this where in the build.gradle? Some context please.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and my issue was that gradle JDK was set to 9. I changed the JDK to 8 (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM) and it worked