# Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.7.2:compile

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build and run a scala/spark program from a terminal, but while building the program I'm getting the following error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

```
[ERROR] '8' is not a valid choice for '-target'
[ERROR] bad option: '-target:8'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.961 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-06T11:39:28+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.7.2:compile (default) on project DisDPMM_2.13: Execution default of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.7.2:compile failed: Compilation failed: InterfaceCompileFailed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

The pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.13.0</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.13</scala.compat.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.13</scala.binary.version>
    <spark.version>3.3.0</spark.version>
    <spec2.version>4.2.0</spec2.version>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>ddMMyyyy</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Scala -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Breeze -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>breeze_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>breeze-natives_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>breeze-viz_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.tongfei</groupId>
        <artifactId>progressbar</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other Dependencies -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.haifengl/smile-scala -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.haifengl</groupId>
        <artifactId>smile-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.sandia.foundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cognitive-foundry</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>json4s-native_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0-M7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dev.ludovic.netlib</groupId>
        <artifactId>blas</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dev.ludovic.netlib</groupId>
        <artifactId>lapack</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version><executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-g:line</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- segmentation.Test -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Tests will be run with scalatest-maven-plugin instead -->
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm using:

- scala 2.13
- scala-maven-plugin: 4.7.2
- spark 3.3.0
- Java-8-
  Thanks a lot!

Comment: `'-target:8'` --> `'-target:1.8'`

Comment: where can i change this ?

Comment: How should I know, without knowing your pom.xml?

Comment: Sorry! I've just added it in the com bellow

Comment: Do oyu set `maven.compiler.target` via command line?

Comment: I only use `mvn package -DskipTests` for compilation

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041527/jvm-1-8-is-not-a-valid-choice-for-target